# C# BotFramework Prompt.Confirm displays too many attempts exception

Tags: c#, botframework

I was recently developing a chatbot using Microsoft's botframework.  I am using prompt.confirm to take user's yes/no input but it shows too many attempts exception when I write basic yes/no. I don't want my bot to display too many attempts exception instead I want to handle it internally. Here's my code.

```
[LuisIntent("None")]
public async Task NoneIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    try
    {
        PromptDialog.Confirm(context, NextQuestionAsync, QuestionPrompt, attempts: 1, promptStyle: PromptStyle.Auto);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Something really bad happened.");
    }
}

public async Task NextQuestionAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> result)
{
    try
    {
        if (await result)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Ok, alarm 0 disabled.");
            //context.Wait(NoneIntent);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("You Said No");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1757

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this issue by overriding the PromptOptions constructor, Thanks to ezequiel. I used PromptDialog.Choice to achieve it however I could also have done it with confirm. Here's what I did

```
    List<string> questions = new List<string>();
    questions.Add("Yes"); // Added yes option to prompt
    questions.Add("No"); // Added no option to prompt
    string QuestionPrompt = "Are you sure?";
    PromptOptions<string> options = new PromptOptions<string>(QuestionPrompt, "", "", questions, 1); // Overrided the PromptOptions Constructor.
   PromptDialog.Choice<string>(context, NextQuestionAsync, options);
```

Comment: PromptConfirm is better for yes/no question. This is kind of a duplicate of my answer. And you are not overriding the constructor; that's a wrong statement.

Comment: Sure... same pattern you did in other questions. Nevermind

Answer (score 4):

You can just override the `TooManyAttempts` message by passing your own string in the [PromptOptions constructor](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/10893730134135dd4af4250277de8e1b980f81c9/CSharp/Library/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L157), which is later used [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/10893730134135dd4af4250277de8e1b980f81c9/CSharp/Library/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L751) to display the message.

Also, have in mind that in the case of the `TooManyAttempts` exception, the way to handle it is in the try/catch of the `ResumeAfter` method (in this case your `NextQuestionAsync` method), surrounding the `await` and not in the caller method.