# how to change default message toomanyattempts

Tags: botframework

I am using prompts. When user types invalid option too many times, simulator throws an exception :

> too many attempts

I tried with try and catch statement but exception message shows again. 
Any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# BotFramework Prompt.Confirm displays too many attempts exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42071335/c-sharp-botframework-prompt-confirm-displays-too-many-attempts-exception)

Comment: It's a little weird. I put try catch in my code, and it throws an exception. In same it uses its own exception method.

It's a little bit difficult and not practical to override existing constructors for implementing simple exception. Just saying.

Comment: Override existing constructor? You don't need to override anything, the message sent in the exception is what you need to change. The message is parameter of the PromptOptions class. This questions is a duplicate of the other one and should be closed.

Comment: Aham ok. So i will change message in this line : 

 `await context.PostAsync(this.MakePrompt(context, promptOptions.TooManyAttempts));`

right ?

Comment: I don't know what your MakePrompt function does. In your code, when you create the prompt, you can pass prompt options. Once you create a prompt option, one of the parameter that accepts is the toomanyattemps message

Comment: So how to send my message for that exception here : 

 `var dialog = new PromptDialog.PromptChoice<string>(new string[] {
                "opt1", "opt2", 
            }, "You can choose : ", "Sorry, that wans't a valid option", 2);`